# Audio playback speed control Chrome extension that works on SoundCloud, and is not global

Tags: audio, chrome

I'm looking for an audio speed control Chrome extension that works on SoundCloud.

I usually use [Playback Rate Controller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/playback-rate-controller/hoaomahcgkefmbbphgnedkllmaincgae?hl=en), but it doesn't work on SoundCloud (it seems that it doesn't recognize there's an audio file).

There's another one called [Global Speed](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/global-speed/jpbjcnkcffbooppibceonlgknpkniiff/related?hl=en), but as it name suggests - it's global, meaning that the playback rate is set for all open tabs (existing or newly opened).

I'm looking for a combination of these two extensions:

1. Allows to set the playback speed for each tab individually.
2. Works on SoundCloud.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Global Speed did not work work on Sound Cloud for me. I was on Brave, a Chromium based browser.

Answer (score 1):

Global Speed has a pin feature to set a custom speed for that tab. In the options page, there's also a setting called "pin by default" that will automatically pin all new tabs (seems like the behavior you want).